# "Variable does not exist: Type" when creating a Task

Tags: apex, tasks

I'm trying to create a `Task` via Apex, and I'm trying to set the Type to "Call":

```
Task task = new Task();
task.Type = 'Call';
task.Subject = 'Paid signup';
task.WhatId = account.Id;
task.Status = 'New';
task.ActivityDate = Date.Today().AddDays(7);
task.OwnerId = account.OwnerId;
task.Description = 'Contact: ' + contact.Name + '\r\n' + 'Contract: ' + contract.ContractNumber;
insert task;
```

And I'm getting the following error on the second line where I assign "Call":

> Line: 2, Column: 6
>
> Variable does not exist: Type

I'm basing my code off this example: https://www.brcline.com/blog/creating-tasks-salesforce-apex

Type definitely exists:

[image]

How do I fix this code so that it works?

Comment: Check if the field has field level permission enabled for your user profile?

Comment: @Raul I'm using the administrator account.

Comment: @Raul You were right. It wasn't _visible_.

Comment: BTW, there is a more compact way of doing this: ```Task task = new Task(Type = 'Call', Subject = 'Paid signup', ...);```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually this problem happens when the FLS is not enabled for the user's profile.

First thing to check in such cases is to create the record from Salesforce UI to verify if the field is visible.

Comment: FLS = Field Level Security